# Why does a prerender error occur only when performing a Next.JS build in GitHub Action?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, build, github-actions, prerender

A prerender error occurs when building in Next.JS, but I don't know why...
The build works fine locally, but this error only occurs in GitHub actions.

My Next.JS version is 13.5.2.
Please take a look and answer if you know the problem. Please..

https://github.com/Team-INSERT/Something_Big_Frontend/actions/runs/6322634986/job/17168617084

try to add env at github actions
but it is not work